# Insertion in Singly Linked List running on infinite loop

Tags: c++

Linked List PrintNode function is running on an infinite loop.

```
class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node * head; //first variable of inked list
void Insert(int x){

    //insertion at beginning
    Node* p = new Node;
    p->data = x;
    p->next = NULL; //when list is empty

    //two scenarios to insert node
    //one when linked list is empty
    if (head == NULL){
       head = p; //head becomes the first node
    }
    //if linked list is not empty
    if (head != NULL){
        p->next = head;
        head = p; //pointing head at the newly created node

    }

}

void PrintNode(Node* head){

    for ( Node * temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next )
    {
        cout << temp->data << "->";
    }

}


int main (){

    head = NULL; //points nowhere
    int n;int x;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ;i ++){

        cout << "Enter element" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        Insert(x);

    }

    PrintNode(head);
}
```

I expect the output to be list printed as for example: 1->2->3-> but,
running on an infinite loop.

Comment: `NULL` isn't the same as `nullptr`, and I'm not sure if `NULL == nullptr`.

Comment: While `NULL` would works in this case (assuming typical definition as 0), it should not be used anymore when it is clear that the type is a pointer for the same reason than one should not assign 0 to a pointer anymore.

Comment: By using a debugger, you should be able to solve a problem like that in less than a minute and it would help you learn from your mistake.

Answer (score 9):

The first `Node` you add ends up pointing at itself.  Take a look at this chunk of code from `Insert`

```
if (head == NULL){
   head = p; //head becomes the first node
}
//if linked list is not empty
if (head != NULL){
    p->next = head;
    head = p; //pointing head at the newly created node

}
```

You'll point `head` at your new `Node`, then enter the next `if` since `head` isn't `NULL`.  If you replace the second `if` with an `else`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Look carefully at this code:

```
if (head == NULL){
   head = p; //head becomes the first node
}
//if linked list is not empty
if (head != NULL){
    p->next = head;
    head = p; //pointing head at the newly created node

}
```

When `head` is `NULL` both branches of code get run resulting in your head node pointing to itself. The correct code would be:

```
if (head == nullptr){
   head = p; //head becomes the first node
}
//if linked list is not empty
else{
    p->next = head;
    head = p; //pointing head at the newly created node

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you update the head pointer as you insert your first element, both if statements will be executed  and the head pointer will never be empty in the second if statement, so it should be if then else, like below

```
if (head == NULL){
   head = p; //head becomes the first node
}
//if linked list is not empty
else if (head != NULL){
   p->next = head;
   head = p; //pointing head at the newly created node

}
```

Comment: Putting the exact opposite condition in the `else if` part usually show a lack of understanding of the language.

Comment: That is quite demotivating. Your help is asked only for error correction, not for extra negative views.